# Render multiple dynamic hyperlink list in html email template

Tags: c#, html, list, asp.net-core

I am trying to send a list with hyperlinks to html email template, the list contains multiple items(path for documents), but I am able to get only one item in the email(first item from the list).

asp.net code:

```
        private string GetEmailBody(List<string> blob)
         {            
            string strContent = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();               
            var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://email template path");

            using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
            using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
            {
                strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }                
            var emailBody = strContent;
            body.Append(emailBody);
                        
              foreach (var path in blob.ToList())
            {
                body.Replace("{{Report.Path}}", path.ToString());
            }
            foreach (var name in fileName.ToList())
            {
                body.Replace("{{Report.Name}}", name.ToString());
            }

            return body.ToString();
        }           
    }
```

blob.ToList contains list of paths.

fileName.ToList contains list of filenames.

Email HTML Template:

```
             <div align="center">
                <p>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                 <a href="{{Report.Path}}" class="button">{{Report.Name}}</a>                       
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </p>
            </div>
```

I have also tried using *ngFor but didnt work out.

I want to display something like this. currently it shows only 1 report, I need all reports from the list
[[image: c1]

Any suggestions/advice and help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your email template has just one `<li>` element (as the list item's template). Your code actually replaces it the first time and all the next times fail to replace (replace nothing). Here you need to do the following steps:

- Find the parent `<ul>` element
- Extract the list item template from the first `<li>` then remove that `<li>`
- Use the extracted list item template to replace with each entry's values to get the list item html.
- Add a new `<li>` element from the replaced html to the parent `<ul>`.

You can use some library to help parsing & modifying XML in general or HTML in particular, such as the `htmlagilitypack`. However it's just one of the tools, the above steps are the most important (kind of base logic/algorithm to implement). Here I introduce a way using `System.Xml.Linq` (or Linq-to-xml) that is built-in the framework. This is more convenient but it requires a strict XML format to work with. I suppose you can ensure that for your email template.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(emailBody);
//NOTE: this supposes there is only one <ul>
var ul = xdoc.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.ToString().ToLower() == "ul")
//the list item template
var li = ul.FirstNode;
//get the actual template
var template = li.CreateNavigator().InnerXml;
//remove the template item, we'll add all later
li.Remove();
//suppose the number of report paths should be equal to the number of filenames
var listItems = blob.Zip(filename, (path,name) => {
                    var liHtml = template.Replace("{{Report.Path}}", path)
                                         .Replace("{{Report.Name}}", name);
                    return new XElement("li", XElement.Parse(liHtml));  
                });
//add the list items to the parent <ul>
foreach(var listItem in listItems){
    ul.Add(listItem);
}

//finally return the processed template
return xdoc.ToString();
```

For invalid xml (from your email template), the code can throw the `XmlException`, you can try-catch that and provide a helpful exception or message to be sent to the client.